# using mongoid on sinatra , model inheritance causing "uninitialized constant" modelname (parent class)

Tags: sinatra, mongoid

I'm using Mongoid on Sinatra . And I use

```
Dir.glob(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),'models','*.rb')).each do |file|
  require file
end
```

to load mongoid model files.

I tried to add a model B inherit from A ,like:

models/a.rb:

```
class A
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :custom_id, type: Integer
end
```

models/b.rb

```
class B < A
  field :title , type: String
  field :body , type: String
end
```

But when I exec the App , I got errors :

```
uninitialized constant A (NameError)
```

So I'm trying to find a solution for this, 
it could be fixed by add:

```
require A
```

at the top of model B , But I think  it may not be a good way to solve it.

So , is there anyother way to fix this??

---

Regards

Comment: There's nothing wrong with adding `require` lines to files that depend on other files, if only to make sure the load order is correct. In your case you'd want to do a `require 'a'` though, or even need to be more specific regarding namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just require your file where you A class is define.

Sinatra has no auto_load system like rails have. So you need doing all of your require needed.

```
require 'a'
class B < A
  field :title , type: String
  field :body , type: String
end
```